# Return variable importance for each iteration in caret package in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm running a random forest model using `R`'s `caret` package, and running `varImp` on the returned object gives me the averaged variable importance across the number of bootstrap iterations. However, I would rather assess variable importance for each iteration. Is this possible using the `caret` package?

Reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
mod <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
         method = "cforest",
         controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 10))
varImp(mod)
```

returns:

```
cforest variable importance
Overall
Petal.Width  100.0000
Petal.Length  86.6279
Sepal.Length   0.5814
Sepal.Width    0.0000
```

what I'm interested in is rather a list of length=number of bootstrap resamples with variable importance for each iteration. This might be possible using some combination of `returnResamp = "all"` and a custom `summaryFunction` but I'm not wise enough to know.

Answer (score 2):

Which bootstrapping iterations do you mean? The ones used internally by `cforest` or the resampling done by `train`?

`train` returns the importance scores produced by the final model object (which may not be the same as "averaged variable importance across the number of bootstrap iterations" , depending on your answer to the first question.)

If you want to get the resampled importance scores over `train`'s resampling, you can trick `rfe` into doing it. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
mod <- rfe(x = iris[, 1:4], y = iris$Species, sizes = 4,
           rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs, 
                                   method = "boot",
                                   number = 5),
           ## pass options to train(), 
           tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 2),
           method = "cforest",
           controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 10))
```

Then the importance scores for each iteration are in `mod$variables`.

Max

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, i came up with with

```
getvarimp <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is(x, "train") & is(x$finalModel, "RandomForest"))
    vi<-party:::varimp
    body(vi)[[length(body(vi))]]<-quote(return(perror))
    vi(x$finalModel)
}

getvarimp(mod)
```

At least for this object type, this seems to be how varImp calucluates it's return value. Specifically, it takes the column means and rescales

```
vi <- colMeans(getvarimp(mod))
(vi-min(vi)) / max(vi)*100
```

Note that each time you run this (or `varImp`) you may get a slightly different result because it uses some stochastic prediction  each time it's run.

There may very well be other ways but I was unable to find any.